# Magento 2: How get All products (2000 products) using Rest API?

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, product-page, get

1. I use Magento2.
2. I have 2000 products.
3. I try to get all products, using Rest API.

My request str.:
GET **https:///rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=1000**.
But this is not enough because the total quantity of products  is 2000.

If I try to use:

- **GET https:///rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=0**
  or
- **GET https:///rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria**.

I received error or empty response. I think the response data is too large. So I think, that I need to use pages.

**QUESTION:** How can I create a Next page, that will start from the last data of the previous page?
**EXAMPLE:**

- I have 20 products;
- 1-st Page includes 10 products (From 1 to 10);
- 2-nd Page should include 11 products(From 10 to 20);

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **currentPage** parameter in the rest API. Like this

```
/V1/products/?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100
```

For detailed info about **currentPage** parameter check this link:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/products.html#currentpage-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can add the limit and current page fields to get the desired quantity of products

V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=limit&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=20&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][3][field]=cur&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][3][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][3][condition_type]=eq